# Audio on headphones not playing when plugged in

Tags: windows, audio, motherboard, speakers, headphones

I just wanted to leave this for future reference so other people that may end up with this problem can fix it. I upgraded to the MSI Z97-GD65 Gaming motherboard and when I plugged in my headphones to the front panel on my computer case, the Realtek HD Audio Manager would come up saying they were plugged in and I made sure "Headphone" was selected, but nothing would play on the headphones. I also made sure that all the drivers were installed and up to date. I should note that I'm using Windows 8.1 (x64) and no other sound cards are installed (except for the built-in one with the motherboard). I know this solution may not work for everyone having this problem, but I thought I'd put it out there just in case it does fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other fixes on the internet that say to make sure `Mute the rear output device, when a front headphone plugged in.` is checked in the settings in Realtek HD Audio Manager, I needed to check `Make front and rear output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously`. I know that having that checked should play audio on both my headphones and speakers at the same time (instead of either or), but for whatever reason it plays only on my headphones (if they're plugged in) or only on my speakers.

[image: Wrong option]
[image: Right option]